# Spring : What is the meaning of curly bracket in URL

Tags: spring, url, parameters, upload, photo

I have the following method in a controller in which I have to upload the picture But I don't know why my request is not found, Can anyone tell me how to pass `userId` in the URL ? Why curly bracket is using here ? and how to pass parameter when curly bracket used ?

I am sending URL like this 
http://localhost:8555/api/uploadAcceptanceLetter/1 but it gives me an error of 404

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uploadAcceptanceLetter/{userId}", produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody AcceptanceLetter uploadAcceptanceLetter(Authentication authentication, @PathVariable("userId") Long userId,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                return photoService.uploadAcceptanceLetter(file , userId);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException( "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because the file was empty");
            }                               
    }
```

Comment: How do you submit this request? Show your html/jquery side. Your method is defined as a POST method, so form submission or ajax POST is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a param **file** in the url
The correct URL should be something like  http://localhost:8555/api/uploadAcceptanceLetter/1?file=something
or try puting a *required=false* on the file parameter and check if request is successful

Comment: What program are you using for the POST request?; You aren't writing the URL in your browser, right?

Comment: I am using POSTMAN

Comment: As the error is 404 is from your request, is your application context **api**?